# where can i find the login page in grails to change the template of login model?

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

Actually when i click login button then it goes to http://localhost:8080/login/auth page and i am not finding any auth.gsp to edit the template of login model.I have used spring security and how to change it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override auth.gsp by creating your own as `/views/login/auth.gsp`

Also see [this](http://guides.grails.org/grails-spring-security-core-plugin-custom-authentication/guide/index.html#customLoginForm) useful tutorial.